# R visNetwork visOptions Not Highlighting Desired Edge using highlightNearest in Undirected Graph

Tags: r, shiny, graph-theory, edges, visnetwork

I have an undirected graph and I'd like for all relevant edges (to and from a particular node) to be highlighted when I click on a node.

```r
library(visNetwork)

nodes = data.frame( id = 1:2 , label = paste('Label', 1:2) )
edges = data.frame( from = 1 , to = 2 )

visNetwork( nodes , edges ) %>%
    visOptions( highlightNearest = list( enabled = TRUE , degree = 0 ) )
```

The above code works just fine when I click on node 1:

[image: The edge is highlighted.]

However, no edge is highlighted when I click on node 2:

[image: The edge remains unhighlighted.]

This is obviously because `highlightNearest` is only highlighting edges `from` a selected node. Is there an option to change this behavior so that `highlightNearest` assumes an undirected graph?

I suspect that my question might be what the author of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532361/visnetwork-highlightnearest-show-only-connected-edges-to-a-selected-node) was getting at. However, I think that my question is more precise, in my humble opinion.

Comment: Also (currently open) github issue on this topic: https://github.com/datastorm-open/visNetwork/issues/369